# How to change color of Autosuggestbox suggestion list in UWP?

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

I stuck at this point, How to change color of Autosuggestbox suggestion list in UWP ? It always shows in Dark Grey in color.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easist way is to override `AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionsListBackground` in `App.xaml`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionsListBackground">White</SolidColorBrush>
</Application.Resources>
```

Or you can generate the default style with the VS/Blend Designer, then locate this line -

```
<ListView x:Name="SuggestionsList" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionsListBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionsListBackground}" DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}" ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" MaxHeight="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListMaxHeight}" Margin="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListMargin}" Padding="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListPadding}">
```

And then replace `Background="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionsListBackground}"` with `Background="White"`.

Answer (score -1):

In your autosuggestbox:

```
<AutoSuggestBox background="transparent"/>
```

Comment: @lindexi this is incorrect. The pop-up background isn't affected at all

Comment: Is it a capital B in background and capital T in transparent?

Comment: It's not that. The background property doesn't control the background of the popup